# Apt update was hung, killed the process, now I cannot run apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

"Apt update" was hung, so I killed the process. After killing the process I tried the command again but am now presented with the error below.

```
admin@ubuntu1804:~# apt upgrade        
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

After running the suggested command I am presented with the below.

```
admin@ubuntu1804:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server:
 ubuntu-server depends on motd-news-config; however:
  Package motd-news-config is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2.10) ...

Configuration file '/etc/issue.net'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** issue.net (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I've never encountered this issue before. Before I go reconfiguring packages Id like to receive some input I there is anything further I should do or inspect before continuing.

Comment: If you think that you have changed `/etc/issue.net` just answer "D" to keep the old /etc/issue.net as suggested. Else answer "Y". Are you curious at what the difference is, use "D" to see..

Comment: Yup this was it, noob status for me. Thanks again.